# Django / Create HTMl file from a form

Tags: django

In my Models.py

```
class Scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField('Scene name', max_length=60,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I have submitted the form in Views.py (simplified version)

```
def add_scenes(request): 
  form = sceneForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   if form.is_valid():
            scenes=form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('add_scenes?submitted=True')
   return render(request,'scenes3d/add_scenes.html',
        {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted})
```

What I would like is : after the form is submitted, a new html is created which would be defined in urls.py with the slug name of my form.

```
path('<str:slug>',views.newpage, name="newpage"),
```

Is it the right way to achieve that ?

Comment: But where are you saving the form, you are only checking validation through `form_valid()`, and also to need to save it through `form.save()`.

Comment: I have edited my post with more detail of views.py

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found. There is no creation, just a way to declare new page inside urls.py

urls.py

```
 path('newpage/<slug:scene_slug>',views.newPage,name='newPage'),
```

views.py

```
def newPage (request, scene_slug):
    sceneToRender = Scenes.objects.get(name=scene_slug)
    return render(request,'scenes3d/new_scene.html',
        {"scene" :sceneToRender, }
    )
```